# VSCode new file function. When I use keyboard shortcuts for new file, the search bar pops up and I have to open a new file from that

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image of the search bar pop up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/94sM1.png)

BTW I'm functioning on MAC. Please excuse me, maybe this is a really simple fix but I'm new to html and vscode, pretty much new to coding in general.

This search bar popping up completely defeats the purpose of keyboard shortcuts. And it's really annoying. How can I stop it from popping up?

Tried going into the keyboard shortcuts on settings but couldn't figure out what I need to alter.